# Where can I get free public raw data?

Tags: resources

*In web development, a mashup is a web page or application that uses and **combines data**, presentation or functionality from two or more sources to create new services.*

There are many sources for getting data (raw information). Governments are good examples.
However many of those cost and have complicated licensing.
For instance SMHI in Sweden sells temperature data meanwhile our neighbor country Norway gives it away for free.

One would say what kind of application are you building and what data do you need?  I would say give me some interesting data and I will do a good mashup of it. I could just plot it on Google maps for instance.

So the question is: **Where can I get free data?**

Note: I'm not interested in data mining using a webcrawler!

Please share your sources with me.

Comment: What kind of data are you looking for? Just any data you can get for free?

Comment: Anything data that could have a meaning to a large amount of people.

Comment: How about http://odata.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @ChrisF: "This page contains the following errors:

error on line 2 at column 29: Char 0x0 out of allowed range
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error." When clicking on the odata link.

Comment: @Chris - It works OK for me, but if you've got a repeatable case report the problem to the team on MSO. I'm just a moderator ;)

Comment: @ChrisF: MSO = meta.SO ? Pardon for not being down with the moderator lingo! lol  Appears to be a chrome browser issue, firefox pulls up the feed but Chrome complains about it.

Comment: @Amir - How about <http://www.eoddata.com>. It has historical stock prices for many world markets.

Comment: That was a good one!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For general information, a good place to start might be [Wikipedia's Open Data page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Data) - specifically the bottom parts of the page ([Organisations promoting open data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Data#Organisations_promoting_open_data), [See also](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Data#See_also), and [External Links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Data#External_links))

I was going to turn the rest of this post into a list of data sources for country and regional based data ... but the [Guardian UK Newspaper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Guardian) has already gone and compiled a [World Government Data Store](http://www.guardian.co.uk/world-government-data) so no point duplicating the effort, instead I'll just point to...

**[guardian.co.uk/world-government-data](http://www.guardian.co.uk/world-government-data)**

...for a catalog of a lot of different country and city level Open Data Initiatives.
(It's not UK based, though it does seem to focus on English-speaking countries.)

At time of edit, it contains data for UK, US, Australia, Canada, New Zealand, and Basque Spain.

One thing not listed on there but worth mentioning is the [Ordnance Survey UK mapping data](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/opendata/).

Comment: The Guardian are also in the nice habit of providing the data which is referenced in their stories much of the time.

Answer (score 6):

There is data all over the place of every type. Best approach is to figure out what type of data you need, find a website that has it, and see if the site offers an API. However, here are some general sources:

- [Freebase](http://www.freebase.com/)
- [MediaWiki API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API)
- [data.gov](http://www.data.gov/)

Answer (score 4):

The [Open Data Protocol](http://www.odata.org/) site lists a number of [live oData services](http://www.odata.org/producers) on its Producers page.

edit> StackExchange has an oData service listed there.

Answer (score 3):

**USA**

[New York Times API](http://developer.nytimes.com/docs/times_newswire_api)

Answer (score 3):

For a comprehensive catalog of US government data and supported formats, look here: http://www.data.gov/

Answer (score 3):

Somebody asked pretty much [the same question](http://www.reddit.com/r/compsci/comments/e6ktk/what_are_the_best_free_data_sets/) on Reddit Compsci a while back... here's what [I had to say then](http://www.reddit.com/r/compsci/comments/e6ktk/what_are_the_best_free_data_sets/c15twur).  I think it all still stands.

Poke around some of these sites, I'm reasonably sure there's something there to catch your interest.

- [/r/datasets](http://datasets.reddit.com)
- [/r/opendata](http://opendata.reddit.com)
- http://www.data.gov
- http://data.australia.gov.au/
- http://data.gov.uk
- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7/locating-freely-available-data-samples/
- http://kevinchai.net/datasets/
- http://infochimps.com/datasets
- http://datamob.org/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_Data#Datasets
- http://theinfo.org/

Depending on what you're trying to do, there are tons and tons of datasets out there.  One that's fun to play with, but might or might not be relevant to you, is the [Enron Email Dataset](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eenron/).  It's the result of a LOT of internal Enron corporate email being subpoenaed and [released to the public](http://www.salon.com/news/feature/2003/10/14/enron/index_np.html) back during the big [Enron scandal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enron_scandal).

And if you can't find exactly the data you want, don't underestimate the possibility of writing your own crawler/scraper.  Depending on what data you want, it may be fairly straightforward to just crawl the web for your own dataset.   There are all sorts of tools - from [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) to [apache droids](http://incubator.apache.org/droids/) - for helping you programmatically retrieve information.

Answer (score 3):

New York City has a number of free [MTA transit data feeds](http://mta.info/developers/).

There's also a lot of other interesting public data sets in NYC such as restaurant health inspection data.

Answer (score 2):

[Calgary Public Data Catalogue](http://calgaryonlinestore.com/category.asp?cat_id=113) has some stuff from the city of Calgary, Alberta, Canada that is freely available.

[Open Data and Internet Democracy Tools workshop](http://calgarydemocracy.ca/events/82) was an event held in Calgary last Saturday about using this data, just as something to disclose.

Answer (score 2):

## Water Data

You can use NOAA to retrieve [massive amounts of data](http://www.glerl.noaa.gov/data/) to play with. I've used it several times and the API isn't half bad. If you don't care about what and simply *how much* that's where I would go.

Answer (score 0):

[Windows Azure Marketplace](https://datamarket.azure.com/) - although as of now, most data sources say 'coming soon'

Answer (score 0):

For those who do AWS, [Amazon Public Datasets](http://aws.amazon.com/publicdatasets) might be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

France recently opened an [open data website](http://www.data.gouv.fr/)

Edit: [Paris](http://opendata.paris.fr/opendata/jsp/site/Portal.jsp) did too