# Where can I locate business data to use in my application?

Tags: resources, data

This [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19419/where-can-i-get-free-public-raw-data) talks about any and all free public raw data which appeared to have valuable pieces but nothing that really provides what I am looking for.

Instead of using a socially defined listing of businesses (foursquare), I would like a business listing data set of registered businesses and associated addresses that could then be searchable based on location (coordinates). The critical need is that the data set should be filterable based on varying criteria (give me all restaurants, coffee shops, etc...).

If the data is free that is great but anywhere that sells this type of data would also suffice. [Infochimps](http://www.infochimps.com/datasets/business-places-by-locationary) looked like a possibility but perhaps something a bit more extensive exists.

Where can I find a free or for fee data set of registered business that is filterable based on type of business and location?

Comment: In the UK, local councils hold this kind of data. AFAK, you should be able to obtain it through a Freedom of Information request.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of places to collect about businesses and their locations:

1. Township, County, State Chamber of Commerce.  I have actually collected a lot business data from such places.  You might have to join, but you do get access to the data.
2. I have never investigated whether the federal government offers business specific info.  But you might want to give it a try -- the government provides data about all sorts of weird stuff.

Answer (score 0):

There are some relevant (though not free) data sources on the Azure DataMarket here:

https://datamarket.azure.com/browse/Data?Query=Company

And this web service from StrikeIron might help (also not free):

http://www.strikeiron.com/Catalog/ProductDetail.aspx?pv=2.0.0&pn=Cortera+Business+Vitals

Answer (score 0):

I have use the data from http://localeze.com/.  It is categorized so you can filter like you said and geocoded, for geographic lookup.  I have an application that uses their data and it is as good as anything else out there.

Pretty expensive though.